# Behavior changes when text gets longer

Tags: html

I'm using the following div structure on my site for layout,

```
<div>
     <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">1</div>
     <div style="float: left;">2</div>
     <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
<div>
     <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">3</div>
     <div style="float: left;">4</div>
     <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

It works nice with this example, the output is like the following,

```
1 2
3 4
```

which I was looking for. However, when I make "4" text longer the behavior changes to the following,

```
1 2
3 
44444444444444444444444444444444
```

while I was expecting the following,

```
1 2
3 44444444444444444444444444444..
  44444
```

I could basically use a two rows, two columns table, instead of struggling with this div problem. However they say using div's is a better practice. So, what is the solution?

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem, are your two outer divs wrapped in something ? Are you fixing the total width somewhere else ?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqoCl

Comment: @Blackbird57 I want my left divs (1,3) have a fixed width as I already set in the question. However, I don't want to set width to my right divs (2,4) I want them to fill the page. In other words, %100 width of remaining width of the page.

Comment: And yes, if I set a fixed width to right divs, it works as I expected. Now, is there any way of setting %100 width to the right divs?

Comment: I admit I couldn't get it to wrap without at least setting a max-width and word-wrap properties. That will wrap the text but won't flow to the edge of the page. I updated that pen if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you expected it will be better to wrap divs 1 and 3 in another one ( or any element, for that matter, if you want to be semantic) and float it to the left with fixed width and 2 and 4 in a second container floated next to it. 
And to get the wrapping you describe you'll have to fix the right container as well, or use max-width as suggested in the comments, 'word-wrap: break-word;' because for the browser this is a long word.

You can do something like this:

```
<div style="width: 30%; float:left;">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 70%; float: left; word-wrap: break-word;">
  <div>2</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle so you can see it in action and play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/gSEtW/

Note: Using only divs is bad, you should do some research on HTML semantics. Using inline styles is also bad, you should use a separate stylesheet.